# Flask-SQLAlchemy not able to connect to remote mysql server: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I'm at the stage where I'm trying to learn how to deploy a flask app and I can't get it to connect to my remote server and I'm getting this error

```
  File "C:\saiscripts\intercept_branch\Payment Web App Project\paymentWebApp\wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
    app = start()
  File "C:\saiscripts\intercept_branch\Payment Web App Project\paymentWebApp\wsgi.py", line 5, in start
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\saiscripts\intercept_branch\Payment Web App Project\paymentWebApp\website\__init__.py", line 31, in create_app
    db.create_all()
  File "C:\Users\saiha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1094, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "C:\Users\saiha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1086, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "C:\Users\saiha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1017, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "C:\Users\saiha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 593, in get_engine
    sa_url, options = self.get_options(sa_url, echo)
  File "C:\Users\saiha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 608, in get_options
    sa_url, options = self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, sa_url, options)
  File "C:\Users\saiha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 933, in apply_driver_hacks
    if sa_url.drivername.startswith('mysql'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

I tried connecting through mysql connector which actually works

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="172.***.*.***",
    user="sai",
    passwd="**********"
    )
```

I've checked the privileges

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sai'@'%';
```

I've checked the `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` files

```
bind-address     = 0.0.0.0
```

So then I thought it would be the way my config is setup even though when I had it as a localhost server it worked fine but I can't figure out the issue

/paymentWebApp/wsgi.py

```
from website import create_app, db
from website.extensions_inits import load_preset_data

def start():
    app = create_app()
    app.app_context().push()
    db.create_all()
    load_preset_data(app, db)
    return app

app = start()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

/paymentWebApp/website/_*init*_.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
DB_NAME = "main"

def create_app():
    #Flask Instance
    app = Flask(__name__)
    #app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    app.config.from_object(config.ProdConfig)
...
```

/paymentWebApp/website/config.py

```
class Config:
    """Base config."""
    #SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = environ.get('SESSION_COOKIE_NAME')
    MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 16*1000*1000
    RECEIPT_FOLDER = '..\\assets\\receipts'
    UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS = ['.jpg', '.png', '.pdf']
    STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
    TEMPLATES_FOLDER = 'templates'

class ProdConfig(Config):
    basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
    load_dotenv('/home/sai/.env')
    env_dict = dict(environ)
    FLASK_ENV = 'production'
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('PROD_DATABASE_URI')
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

Comment: `PROD_DATABASE_URI` isn't set in the environment

Comment: @snakecharmerb I thought this was wrong because it wouldn't work on the server either but I actually had to restart gunicorn. Thank You!